# Cannot update product name using productRepository in Admin Store ( Store 0 )

Tags: magento2.3, product-attribute, repository, crud

I'm trying to update a product using productRepository ( migrating from a flow using product factory with load ).

Problem is tha when updating the name it is updating in store 1 ( default store ) but not in store 0 ( admin store view )

Bellow there is a sample code

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    $product = $productRepository->getById('product id here', true, 0);

    $product->setName('ts');
    $productRepository->save($product);
```

Newly created products have only one name in admin view , using the code above a new entry is added in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table for store view 1 leaving store view 0 unchanged.

The only way to update the title seems using $product->save(). Is there any other way without using $product->save() ?

Is seems very strange to me, i'm running this code from a console command and i've already set the state to `adminhtml`

I'm running Magento 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action $productAction
```

for:

```
$this->productAction->updateAttributes(
    [$row->getProductId()], //array with product id's
    [
        $row->getAttributeCode() => $row->getAttributeValue(),
        $row->getOtherAttributeCode() => $row->getOtherAttributeValue()
    ],
    $storeId
);
```

But you dont have to load product from specific store.

```
$product = $productRepository->getById('product id here');
```

should be fine.

If You need to use ProductRepo, I think You can try to set storeId on product before save, or You will have to set storeId as current store

```
$this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore(0);
```

but its not good solution.

Comment: You are right, i can update specific attributes one by one, but there seems no way to save and update the product as a whole ( in admin store view). Such a shame, Magento doesn't provide a standard way of handling product data.

Comment: Oh If you want to save attribute for whole stores just use `$product = $productRepository->getById('product id here');`, then set attribute and save. should be fine. However! If on product on specific store for ttribute is unselect checkbock `use default values / values from default store`, You have to check it, or ser valuses store by store